# How to choose pseudo-random values in an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I know how to sort through an array like this

```
 var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
```

but what I am trying to do is use this in a loop to pick values from my array that I haven't picked with this function before.

In other words, let's say my array contains apples, bananas, and oranges. i want to be able to pick all three of those out randomly, but I don't want to pick able to pick out the same one more than once.(I hope this made sense)

Comment: So if you don't want to find an item in array, then what are you looking for? I am confused

Comment: ya after rereading this I'm going to edit. One second.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-repeating+random+%5Bjavascript%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the item from the array, so it will not be selected again

```
var rand = myArray.length ? myArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length), 1)[0] : undefined;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9n2kqpan/)

Note: It will modify the original array, so if you want to keep the original array as it was you need to keep a different copy

Comment: ya I want to keep the array the same if that is possible.

Comment: @TandyRayes see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9n2kqpan/3/